# SQL: create new record based on several ones

Tags: sql-server

I have a question about sql query. Assume we have one table

**Reports**:

```
+----+-------------+---------+--------+
| ID | reporter_id | subject | report |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+
| 1  |     1       |    A    |  "OK"  |
| 2  |     1       |    B    |  "OK"  |
| 3  |     1       |    c    |"NOT OK"|
| 4  |     2       |    A    |  "OK"  |
| 5  |     2       |    C    |  "OK"  |
+----+-------------+---------+--------+
```

Now, what I want to do is to select all the reports for each reporter_id and produce the following table:

```
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| reporter_id | report_subjectA | report_subjectB | report_subjectC |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|      1      |      "OK"       |      "OK"       |    "NOT OK"     |
|      2      |      "OK"       |       NULL      |      "OK"       |
+-------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Is is possible to do that?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is. But what have you tried, what is the logic, what is the issue? Is it not possible that you will get other subjects in future than these three? What if there are an `OK` and an `NOT OK` row for the same subject and reporter-id?

Comment: I'm working with Yii and I would like to simulate a view table, since views are not supported by yii. The subjects will always be 3 and it is not possible that the same reporter reports "OK" and "NOT OK" for the same subject, meaning that there cannot be two records like (id:10, reporter_id:1, report:OK) and (id:10, reporter_id:1, report:NOT OK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
SELECT  
    reporter_id, 
    MIN(CASE WHEN UPPER([subject]) = 'A' THEN report ELSE NULL END)  report_subjectA,
    MIN(CASE WHEN UPPER([subject]) = 'B' THEN report ELSE NULL END)  report_subjectB,
    MIN(CASE WHEN UPPER([subject]) = 'C' THEN report ELSE NULL END)  report_subjectC
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY
    reporter_id
```

Comment: Thanks I just tried this and works like a charm. I had maybe to specify that Im on mysql and does there exists pivot for mysql?

Comment: This is pivot of my sql. :)

Comment: Ahh but there isn't a Pivot operator in mysql. Btw thanks, I'm now trying to translate the query in yii.

Answer (score 1):

If subjects are unlimited, use this:

```
SELECT * INTO #src FROM
(VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A',   'OK'  ),
    (2, 1, 'B',   'OK'  ),
    (3, 1, 'C', 'NOT OK'),
    (4, 2, 'A',   'OK'  ),
    (5, 2, 'C',   'OK'  )
    )T(ID, reporter_id, subject, report)

DECLARE @columns nvarchar(MAX) = STUFF((
SELECT DISTINCT ',[Report Subject '+subject+']'
FROM #Src
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT reporter_id, ''Report Subject ''+subject Title, report
    FROM #Src
) T
PIVOT
(MAX(report) FOR Title IN ('+@columns+')) P'

EXEC (@sql)
```

If there is only 3, use simplified `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT reporter_id, 'Report Subject '+subject Title, report
    FROM #Src
) T
PIVOT
(MAX(report) FOR Title IN ([Report Subject A], [Report Subject B], [Report Subject C])) P
```

Both return:

```
reporter_id   Report Subject A   Report Subject B   Report Subject C
-----------   ----------------   ----------------   ----------------
1             OK                 OK                 NOT OK
2             OK                 NULL               OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
declare @id int,@a char(10),@b char(10),@c char(10)
declare @reports table (reporter_id int, report_subjectA char(10), report_subjectB char(10), report_subjectC char(10))
declare c cursor for 
select distinct reporter_id  from reports
open c
fetch next from c into @id
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
set @a=NULL
set @B=NULL
set @c=NULL
if exists(select report from reports where subjects='A' and reporter_id =@id) set @a=(select report from reports where subjects='A' and reporter_id =@id)
if exists (select report from reports where subjects='B' and reporter_id =@id) set @b=(select report from reports where subjects='B' and reporter_id =@id)
if exists (select report from reports where subjects='C' and reporter_id =@id) set @c=(select report from reports where subjects='C' and reporter_id =@id)
insert into @reports values (@id,@a,@b,@c)
fetch next from c into @id
end
close c
deallocate c

select * from @reports
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 3 subjects.

```
Select reporter_id, report_subjectA, report_subjectB, report_subjectC from
(
    Select reporter_id, report, rep_sub = 'report_subject' + [Subject] from TableReports r
) SourceT
Pivot 
(
    max(report) for rep_sub in ([report_subjectA],[report_subjectB],[report_subjectC])
) AS PivotedT
```